# Javascript : Create regex for Url match

Tags: javascript

**Regex** : 
    (^|\s)((https?://)?[\w-]+(.[\w-]+)+.?(:\d+)?(/\S*)?)

Above regex should not pass for below Url.

www.google

**Test criteria:**

Match:

**Pass:** http: //example.com
**Pass:** http: //example.com/
**Pass:** http: //example.com/super
**Pass:** https: //example.com/super/
**Pass:** example.com/super 
**Pass:** example.com 
**Pass:** example.com/su-per_duper/?add=yes&subtract=no 
**Pass:** example.com/archive/index.html 
**Pass:** twitter.com/#!/reply 
**Pass:** example.com/234ret2398oent/234nth 
**Pass:** codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/464 
**Pass:** crazy.wow.really.example.com/?cat=nth%3E 
**Pass:** example-example.com 
**Pass:** example1.com

Not Match(This is working correctly):

**Pass:** example 
**Pass:** super/cool 
**Pass:** Good Morning 
**Pass:** i:can 
**Pass:** hello.

Here is a test that might help clarify a bit https://regex101.com/r/pdGwy6/5

I apologize for the lack of clarity,Please help me.

Comment: There isn't a real way to tell the difference between things such as `crazy.wow.really.example.com` and `abcwww.google.com`. Without having lists of valid sites.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek My regex is worked for all scenarios, but this sholud not passed for two urls are **www.goo** and **abcwww.google.com**

Comment: I don't think you understand my last comment, what you are asking is **not** possible without having a list of valid websites. The regex doesn't have any idea the difference between `"abcwww"` or `"www"` or `"crazy"`, it's all just words that you have matched.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks to help me